# fetch from table with conditions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables hotels and company_hotels. In which hotel table consist of Id, Hotel_Name, Destination_Id and company_hotels consist of Id, Company_Id, Hotel_Id. I want to search same hotels with Company Ids 1 and 2 with Destination_Id = 10

**Hotel Table**

```
1 hotel 1 10
2 hotel 2 11
3 hotel 3 10
```

**Company hotels**

```
1 1 1
2 1 3
3 2 1
```

for the above example i need the result hotel 1 as the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
select h.Id,h.Hotel_Name
from hotel h
inner join  company_hotels ch on ch.Hotel_Id = h.Id
where 
ch.Company_Id IN (1,2)
AND h.Destination_Id = 10
```

**UPDATE 1**

From the updated comments the query should return hotels which has both company ids 1 and 2 not all the hotels having either 1 or 2

```
select h.Id,h.Hotel_Name
from hotels h
inner join  company_hotels ch on ch.Hotel_Id = h.Id
where 
ch.Company_Id IN (1,2)
AND h.Destination_Id = 10
group by h.Id
having count(h.Id) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9025d/3

Comment: But it will give all the hotels with company Id 1 and 2. I want only same hotels.

Comment: u mean a hotel can have 2 company ID ?

Comment: yes. i updated some data in above question. means company1 and 2 select the hotel1 in destination 10

Comment: check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9025d/2 and please update the question with the data that u are expecting.

Comment: for your example i need only hotel aa. because aa satisfies both destination id = 10 and company id = 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

join on hotel_id

```
Select * from company_hotels inner join hotel
on hotel.id=company_hotels.hotel_id 
where company_hotel.company_id in (1,2) 
and hotel.destination_id=10
```